# In React Native, how to have access to the result of the selection of an image in the image Library?

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if there exist an "event hook" for the action of selecting an image with the ImagePicker module ?

I.e., when the ImagePicker is launched, we have access to the image gallery and we can select one or multiple images, when one select an image I would like to compute a uint8array of this image and to store it somewhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ImagePicker returns the image URI - `file:///path/to/local/image.jpg`  reference to image data on the device.

With image URI, fetch binary image data with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and upload binary to your remote server.

```js
  const arrayBufferData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };

     // XMLHttpRequest support blob, arraybuffer for  binary data
    // blob is recommended while supported by your server.
    //
    xhr.responseType = "arrayBuffer";
    xhr.open("GET", "file:///path/to/local/image.jpg", true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

const imageData = new Uint8Array(arrayBufferData);

// You can upload image data now
```

Comment: @ailauli69 check a new solution

Comment: Thanks, so this is a way to directly fetch arrayBuffer data from image file, which can also be useful for me. But what I was really asking is : once the library is open (for us to choose images), when I select an image (and before I confirm the selection), is there a hook corresponding to this situation ?

Comment: ImagePicker returns `base64` image data. If your remote server support you can simply use `base64`